# How to handle internet slow status in android application with web service?

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2, socketexception

```
public class NewClass extends Activity

{
 public final String NAMESPACE = "**";
public final String URL = "***";

public final String SOAP_ACTION_1 = "**";
public final String METHOD_NAME_1 = "***";

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new FeaturesHomes().execute();
}
}



    public class FeaturedHomes extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Wait", "Data Loading..");
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (mAllMethods.check_Internet()==true) {

                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_1); 
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);

                try {
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_1, envelope);
                    SoapObject mSoapObjectCompanyDetailResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
                    Object re= null;
                    re = envelope.getResponse();
                    System.out.println("Response "+re.toString());
                    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(re.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(StaticValues.FeaturedCommunitiesArray);
                    JSONArray jArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("RateLog");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        mGetFeaturedProperty = new GetFeaturedProperty();
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceID(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceId));
                        String s=AllMethods.MakeWord(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceTitle));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceTitle(s);
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceAddressStreet(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceAddress));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceCountry(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceCountry));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceDesc(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceDesc));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceAddressPincode(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidencePincode));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceState(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceState));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResidenceCity(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResidenceCity));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResiLatitude(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResiLatitude));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setResiLongitude(objJson.getString(StaticValues.ResiLongitude));
                        mGetFeaturedProperty.setImage(objJson.getString(StaticValues.Image));

                        mArrayListFeaturedProperties.add(mGetFeaturedProperty);

                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject objJson1 = jArray.getJSONObject(j);
                        GetFeaturedProperty mGetFeaturedProperty1 = new GetFeaturedProperty();
                        mGetFeaturedProperty1.setRating(objJson1.getString("OverAllRate"));
                        mArrayListTempFeaturedProperties.add(mGetFeaturedProperty1);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                mAllMethods.ShowDialog(getActivity(), "Validate", "Network not Available");
            }


            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (mProgressDialog!=null) {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            if (mAllMethods.isNetError) {
                mAllMethods.ShowDialog(getActivity(), "Validation", "Your internet is slow");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Rating SIze "+mArrayListTempFeaturedProperties.size());
                System.out.println("Ac SIze "+mArrayListFeaturedProperties.size());
                if (mArrayListFeaturedProperties.size()>0) {

                     mMap.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListFeaturedProperties.size(); i++) {
                              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                                double lat =Double.parseDouble(mArrayListFeaturedProperties.get(i).getResiLatitude());
                                double lng =Double.parseDouble(mArrayListFeaturedProperties.get(i).getResiLongitude());
                                final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat,lng);

                                GetFeaturedProperty firstEventInfo = new GetFeaturedProperty(latLng,mArrayListFeaturedProperties.get(i).getResidenceID(),mArrayListFeaturedProperties.get(i).getResidenceTitle());


                                  Marker firstMarker = placeMarker(firstEventInfo);

                                  eventMarkerMap = new HashMap<Marker, GetFeaturedProperty>();

                                  eventMarkerMap.put(firstMarker, firstEventInfo);

                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat ,lng), 8.0f));
                        }
                        mNewadapter=new NewCustomAdapter(getActivity(),mArrayListFeaturedProperties,mArrayListTempFeaturedProperties);
                        mGridView.setAdapter(mNewadapter);

                }
            }


        }
    }
```

**AllMethdos.java**

```
public class AllMethods {

Activity mActivity;
ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo ;
boolean isNetError=false;
public AllMethods() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

  public boolean check_Internet()
{
    mConnectivityManager= (ConnectivityManager)    mActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     mNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(mNetworkInfo != null && mNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting())
    {
        isNetError = false;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        isNetError = true;
        return false;
    }
}

 }
```

hello friends when i run above code then sometime it works fine but when in my device `Internet` getting slow then it will take much time so i already check condition that if any internet error then show dialog message for that but it will not display right now and data not loaded (means blank) and proggres dialog dismiss and give me error message like

```
03-20 18:06:23.337: W/System.err(20648): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to seniorhomes.worldexplorer.ca/208.91.198.99 (port 80) after 20000ms
03-20 18:06:23.337: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:150)
03-20 18:06:23.337: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-20 18:06:23.337: W/System.err(20648):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-20 18:06:23.337: W/System.err(20648):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
03-20 18:06:23.337: W/System.err(20648):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:872)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
03-20 18:06:23.347: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
03-20 18:06:23.357: W/System.err(20648):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
03-20 18:06:23.357: W/System.err(20648):    at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
03-20 18:06:23.357: W/System.err(20648):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:146)
03-20 18:06:23.357: W/System.err(20648):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
03-20 18:06:23.367: W/System.err(20648):    at pkg.android.rootways.retirement.JobEventDetailListActivitty$GetJobList.doInBackground(JobEventDetailListActivitty.java:405)
03-20 18:06:23.367: W/System.err(20648):    at pkg.android.rootways.retirement.JobEventDetailListActivitty$GetJobList.doInBackground(JobEventDetailListActivitty.java:1)
03-20 18:06:23.367: W/System.err(20648):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
03-20 18:06:23.367: W/System.err(20648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-20 18:06:23.367: W/System.err(20648):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-20 18:06:23.377: W/System.err(20648):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
03-20 18:06:23.377: W/System.err(20648):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-20 18:06:23.377: W/System.err(20648):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-20 18:06:23.377: W/System.err(20648):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to sometime your server not responding your request which you call from your application so you depends upon network speed as well as your server speed for responding back quickly